# Does `dict.copy()` iterate? Can I use it while modifying the dict in another thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, dictionary

I have a `dict` shared between two threads. One thread is adding and removing entries, and the other thread now needs to iterate over the dict and derive some data from it.

In Python 2, there was `items()` which would return a list and didn't necessarily iterate over the `dict`. The suggested way to iterate over a `dict` you want to modify in Python 3 seems to be to iterate over `list(mydict.items())`, but that seems like it should only work for one thread; another thread might add or remove items while `list()` is still using an iterator over the dictionary view returned by `items()`, right?

There is a `copy()` method on `dict`; the [documentation doesn't suggest](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.copy) that it can throw a `RuntimeError` like dictionary and dictionary view iterators can. **Can I safely use `copy()` to snapshot a `dict` that is being modified by another thread?** Then I can just iterate over the snapshot.

Comment: The question you should be asking is not whether it iterates (how else can it copy everything?), but whether it's an atomic operation.

Comment: Instead of depending of the current behaviof of dict-copy, you could just as well add a threading.Lock object to your code, and have it not only be safe in a particular Python version, but also, look safe, and be future proof.

Answer (score 5):

Definitionally, `dict.copy` must iterate; you can't copy all the key/value pairs without iterating.

The rest of the answer depends on your interpreter. It's a safe/atomic operation on the CPython reference interpreter (where the GIL ensures the entire `copy` operation occurs as a result of a single `CALL_METHOD` bytecode, and the GIL can only be released *between* bytecodes), but there's no language guarantee backing this up in general. **If your code *might* run on GIL-free Python interpreters with truly simultaneous threads, you'll need to use locking.**

Note that not all seemingly atomic `dict` operations will work this way. For example, `dict.setdefault` will be atomic on CPython *if* all keys involved are built-in types implemented in C (so invoking their `__hash__` and `__eq__` can't end up back in the interpreter loop, during which the GIL could be released), but it won't work for user-defined class instances with `__hash__`/`__eq__` defined in Python-level code. `dict.copy` happens to be safe because:

1. The hashes are cached in the `dict`, and need not be recomputed
2. Nothing is being added or removed from the `dict`, so collisions are impossible while building the new `dict` (they have optimized code paths for when keys are being inserted and the keys being inserted are guaranteed not to be equal to any existing key, which can only be used in special cases like `copy`).